# Change point size in the last rows of a QTableWidget

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have a table with some rows having the default point-size font. I would like to change the point-size only in the last row.

Everything I found on the internet changed the point-size of the whole table or I got the error that "cell = QTableWidgetItem" did not support changing fonts

My piece of code

```
def fill_Turni(self, table: QTableWidget, year, month, editable=False):
    table.setRowCount(0)
    daysinmonth = calendar.monthrange(int(year), int(month))[1]
    fake_row = 0
    table.insertRow(fake_row)
    table.setRowHeight(fake_row, 20)
    i = 1
    while i <= daysinmonth:
        a_date = datetime.date(int(year), int(month), i)
        a_dow = a_date.strftime("%a")
        dow = a_dow[0:3]
        dow = dow.lower()
        cell = QTableWidgetItem(str(dow))
        table.setItem(fake_row, i, cell)
        i += 1

    for i in range (7):
        fake_row = fake_row + 1
        table.insertRow(fake_row)
        table.setRowHeight(fake_row, 20)
        text = Functions.shift_table[i]
        cell = QTableWidgetItem(text)
        cell.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        table.setItem(fake_row, 0, cell)
    i = 1
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(user='a', password='b', database='c')
    cursor = conn.cursor(buffered=True, dictionary=True)
    value = {}
    while i <= daysinmonth:
        query = "SELECT * FROM damntable WHERE year = '%s' AND month = '%s' AND day = '%s' " %(year, month, i)
        cursor.execute(query)
        results = cursor.fetchall()
        self.numrows = int(cursor.rowcount)
        for row, data in enumerate(results):
            value[0] = data['morn']
            value[1] = data['noon']
            value[2] = data['even']
            value[3] = data['req']
            value[4] = data['req_m']
            value[5] = data['req_p']
            value[6] = value[3] + value[4] + value[5]
            fake_row = 0
            for zz in range (7):
                fake_row = fake_row + 1
                z_value = value[zz]
                if z_value == 0:
                    z_value =''
                cell = QTableWidgetItem(str(z_value))
                cell.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
                table.setItem(fake_row, i, cell)
        i = i + 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the font of a QTableWidgetItem then you must use setFont() method:

```
font = cell.font()
font.setPointSize(20)
cell.setFont(font)
```

But if you want it to be something dynamic then you must use a delegate:

```py
LAST_POINT_SIZE = 20


class Delegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def initStyleOption(self, option, index):
        super().initStyleOption(option, index)
        if index.row() == index.model().rowCount() - 1:
            font = QFont(option.font)
            font.setPointSize(LAST_POINT_SIZE)
            option.font = font
            option.fontMetrics = QFontMetrics(font)

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        editor = super().createEditor(parent, option, index)
        if index.row() == index.model().rowCount() - 1:
            font = QFont(option.font)
            font.setPointSize(LAST_POINT_SIZE)
            editor.setFont(font)
        return editor
```

```py
delegate = Delegate(table)
table.setItemDelegate(delegate)
```

Comment: First option has no effect, the delegato works correctly